# cv2.solve fail to return least-squares solution

Tags: python, opencv, linear-algebra

I want to use `cv2.solve` to solve the linear matrix equation a*X=b.

The input matrices are of type float32, a has shape of (10,4) and b is (10,1).

Using numpy i get correct output :

```
x, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=-1)
print(x)

[[ 0.81440514]
 [ 0.08010263]
 [46.14513   ]
 [58.802303  ]]
```

When trying to the same thing with opencv i get an error which i cannot understand :

```
x = cv2.solve(a, b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yossib/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-22-611d9131dc5c>", line 1, in <module>
    cv2.solve(a, b)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp:1093: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (method != DECOMP_LU && method != DECOMP_CHOLESKY) || is_normal || src.rows == src.cols in function 'solve'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an explicit solution method argument to `cv2.solve`, e.g.:

```
x = cv2.solve(a, b, flags=cv2.DECOMP_QR)
```

By default, opencv uses LU decomposition to solve linear systems ([that's the default value of flags argument](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#solve)).
But LU decomposition is only used for square matrices, and is not applicable to your case (where the linear system is overdetermined). `DECOMP_SVD`, `DECOMP_QR`, and/or `DECOMP_NORMAL` are better suited for your case.

Comment: Thanks, using DECOMP_SVD indeed works and produce same output as numpy.linalg.lstsq.
Too bad opencv error messages are so unclear.